# Solve this system of linear congruences: 7x+3y is conruent to 10(mod 16) and 2x+5y is congruent to 9(mod 16).

Tags: number-theory

Solve this system of linear congruences: $7x+3y$ is conruent to 10(mod 16) and $2x+5y$ is congruent to 9(mod 16).

I've looked at similar questions and for some reason I can't get an answer to come out...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**.  With some reservations, you can treat congruence equations in the same sort of way that you treat ordinary equations.  Starting with
$$7x+3y\equiv10\pmod{16}\ ,\qquad 2x+5y\equiv9\pmod{16}\ ,$$
take $5$ times the first minus $3$ times the second to get
$$29x\equiv 23\pmod{16}\ .$$
If you have studied congruences you should now be able to solve this for $x$, and you can then substitute back to find $y$.